# JSF adding object to arrayList

Tags: java, jsf, object, arraylist

I have been trying to add an Student object to an arrayList using Java Server Faces, but I can figure it out how to do it, here is hat i got so far. what method I need to use, and where do i put it?

Index

```
<h:body>
    <h:form >
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" >
            <h:outputText value="Name"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{student.name}" required="true">
            <h:outputText value="Age"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{student.age}" required="true">
                <p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{student.showGo()}"><!--go to another JSF page-->
                   <!-- ActionListener needed-->
                </p:commandButton>  
        </h:panelGrid>  
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Student bean

```
@Named(value = "student")
@RequestScoped
public class StudentBean {


private String name;
private int age;

public StudentBean(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}


public StudentBean() {
}

public String showGo(){
    return "show";
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

List bean

```
@Named(value = "list")
@RequestScoped
public class List {

private ArrayList<StudentBean> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
public List() {
}

 public void addStudent()
{
    StudentBean student = new StudentBean();
    studentList.add(student);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Can you describe it?

Comment: User imputs name and age, I want to store name and age in an object of the class StudentBean so then I can add that object to an ArrayList<StudentBean>

Comment: And where should `#{student.showGo()}` lead you or what should be displayed in `show.xhtml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure that I understood you. But if your intention is just to save `name` and `age` in an object and add it to a list, the following should serve the purpose:

1. The managed bean in `SessionScope` so that you can access it in the next page (`show.xhtml??):

   ```
   @Named(value = "student")
   @SessionScoped
   public class StudentBean {

    private ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

        private String name;
        private int age;

        public StudentBean(String name, int age) {
           this.name = name;
           this.age = age;
        }


         public StudentBean() {
         }

         public String showGo(){
            Stundent student = new Student(name, age);
            studentList.add(student);

            return "show";
        }

       public int getAge() {
           return age;
       }

       public void setAge(int age) {
           this.age = age;
       }

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }

       public List<Student> getStundentList() {
           return studentList;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Define just a simple `Sundent` class as JavaBean:

   ```
   public class Stundent {
       private String name;
       private int age;

       public Stundent() { }

       public Stundent(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
       }

       // getters and setters
   }
   ```

   If you still have a question leave me a comment.

Comment: Thanks, it works!...one last question: why the need for a student class?

Comment: The Student class represents the domain object;. it is the reason why you write the program. You can pass it around different tiers of the application. But the StudentBean is managed by the runtime environment; in this case by the web container? You can not create or destroy it: and its main function is controlling the logic of the GUI: navigation, event handling,...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do something like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{list.addStudent()}"></p:commandButton>
```

and in **addStudent**:

```
public String addStudent()
{
    StudentBean student = new StudentBean();
    studentList.add(student);
    return "show";
}
```